# Neo4jPhp relations

Tags: php, neo4j

I'm playing around with Neo4j in my php project. I currently created around 100.000 nodes but I wonder how to put some random relations to do some tests on the setup concerning speed.

The nodes have only random properties so I would need a way to put relations using the id.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just find the highest ID in use on nodes, and then randomly generate a 2 node-ids to connect, and retry if there are no nodes on these IDs?